# How to deal with nested data in pandas dataframe via "for loop"?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nested

I have got a nested data in pandas dataframe and I want to flatten the column, "names" by using "pd.Dataframe ()" function. When I attempt to flatten via "for loop" it produces 5 different dataframe list, which I do not expect to have and rather only one dataframe list with all values listed. I have already tried "concat" or "append" methods but it did not give any clue to move forward. Any help/comment is welcome, thanks so much. Here is my "for loop":

```
            x=df['names'].iloc[0:4]
                     
            name_data = pd.DataFrame(x)

           
            data_row=[]
            for data in x:
                data_row =pd.DataFrame(data)
        
                st.write(data_row)
```

[image: nested pandas dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to concat the 5 tables in the example images above to only 1 table and show the result table on streamlit.

All you have to do are

- change from `data_row =pd.DataFrame(data)` to `data_row += [pd.DataFrame(data)]`
- After loop for loop finished

  - you can concat all dataframes in `data_row` to one dataframe by using `data_row = pd.concat(data_row)`
  - and then, show the result table with streamlit by using `st.write(data_row)`

Here is example for tackling your problem.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'names': [[{'name':'a'},{'name':'b'}], [{'name':'c'}]]
})

x=df['names'].iloc[0:2]

data_row = []
for data in x:
    data_row += [pd.DataFrame(data)]
data_row = pd.concat(data_row)

st.write(data_row)
```

or you can create the list of dictionary and create dataframe by using the example below

```py
data_row = []
for data in x:
    data_row += data
data_row = pd.DataFrame(data_row)
```