# how to "concat" pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have got a normalized .json data from a .json Api, in which .json data were represented in a paginated way. I can simply import the data and list as pandas dataframe with the following for loop, but it seems it produces separate dataframes with the same index [0]. What I want is to merge all dataframes under the same header columns with a new index value beginning with [0].

```
    for links in url: 
        url_data=session.get(links).json()
        df_nested_list = pd.json_normalize(url_data)
        st.write(df_nested_list)
```

My attempt with the "[concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72407240/how-to-deal-with-nested-data-in-pandas-dataframe-via-for-loop/72408266#72408266)" method was only producing the same result since the index was already set and could not be re-set. I am looking for a solution to merge the separated dataframes and re-index the dataset in order to select or filter a number of lines (not all the lines since it is a large dataset. Any comment/support is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Try playing around with `reset_index`. Also it would be helpful if you posted what you tried so far with `concat`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of dataframes, and concat them at the end.

```
dfs = []
for links in url:
    url_data = session.get(links).json()
    df = pd.json_normalize(url_data)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

```
df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(session.get(l).json()) for l in url], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response @BeRTme.It is almost the correct answer. I have recently tested and it seems it works to a certain extend and can not merge all dataframes coming from the paginated .json. but creates block of dataframes.

[image]